# MVC 4 - Uploadify 500 (swf does extra request)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

In MVC 4 I got an /Book/Create page. In this page there is an EditorTemplate with the following code:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```

Also I've made a javascript file which contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        swf: '/Content/Flash/uploadify.swf',
        debug: true,
        auto: false
    });
});
```

Now I'm using Uploadify 3.2 with the .swf file and everything works fine.
Except for the initialization of the page, first /Book/Create is called.
Then after this /Book/ is called (the Index action).

Firebug says the following:

**Answer headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["fa95eddf-e604-4678-adb3-9f3ea445b7e2"]
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcVHJhY2VIZXJcUHJvamVjdHNcVHJhY2VcVHJhY2UuSGVyVUlcQmFiZVw=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2012 13:49:38 GMT
Content-Length: 1342
```

**Request headers**

```
GET /Book/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:42740
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:42740/Content/Flash/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1348753776045
```

**SWF DEBUG**

```
---SWFUpload Instance Info---
Version: 2.2.0 2009-03-25
Movie Name: SWFUpload_0
Settings:
    upload_url:               /Book/uploadify.php
    flash_url:                /Content/Flash/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1348753776045
    use_query_string:         false
    requeue_on_error:         false
    http_success:             
    assume_success_timeout:   30
    file_post_name:           Filedata
    post_params:              [object Object]
    file_types:               *.*
    file_types_description:   All Files
    file_size_limit:          0
    file_upload_limit:        0
    file_queue_limit:         999
    debug:                    true
    prevent_swf_caching:      true
    button_placeholder_id:    file_upload
    button_placeholder:       Not Set
    button_image_url:         /Book/
    button_width:             120
    button_height:            30
    button_text:              
    button_text_style:        color: #000000; font-size: 16pt;
    button_text_top_padding:  0
    button_text_left_padding: 0
    button_action:            -110
    button_disabled:          false
    custom_settings:          [object Object]
Event Handlers:
    swfupload_loaded_handler assigned:  false
    file_dialog_start_handler assigned: true
    file_queued_handler assigned:       true
    file_queue_error_handler assigned:  true
    upload_start_handler assigned:      true
    upload_progress_handler assigned:   true
    upload_error_handler assigned:      true
    upload_success_handler assigned:    true
    upload_complete_handler assigned:   true
    debug_handler assigned:             true

SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: Build Number:           SWFUPLOAD 2.2.0
SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             /Book/uploadify.php
SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:      
SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        0 bytes
SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      0
SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       999
SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG:
```

I think it has something to do with the **button_image_url** in the swf debug. But even if I set the **buttonImage** property in the javascript it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was hard to find the answer on google for this problem (searched over an hour) so I'll add the answer to this post also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12369252/267740